# build eclipse feature from existing plugins with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, jenkins

Is it possible to build an eclipse feature from already existing plugins (built with ant)? The plugins are built as .class files in the bin folder and could easily packed as .jar files with MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml like normal plugins. I've tried to build this all with ant but as it seems maven tycho is the standard way to build an eclipse feature now but I don't want to build the plugins with maven again, if it could use the existing ones...

I hope somebody understands my problem and could help :)

thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

You need to create a p2 repository containing your plugins. After that you can add a repository in the pom file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>p2pluginrepo</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>file:///c:/myrepo/</url>
    </repository>
</repository>
```

But i think the better solution would be to migrate the plugins to maven tycho.